# No sqlite3.exe in SQLite3 download folder for Windows 64 Bit

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to install SQLite 3 on my Windows 10 64 bit from [SQLite download page](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) and I tried the `sqlite-dll-win64-x64-3170000.zip` from "Precompiled Binaries for Windows" section on the page:

[image]

but when I unzip the file there are only two files "sqlite3.def`and`sqlite3.dll`:

[image]

Where is the `sqlite3.exe`? As far as I know we should have all these three files together.

```
sqlite3.def
sqlite3.dll
sqlite3.exe
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37071554/sqlite3-installation-issues-on-windows-8-1?rq=1

Answer (score 35, accepted):

- Download the "tools" package from the download page (current direct link:  https://www.sqlite.org/2017/sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3170000.zip)
- Unzip to get:
  [image]

**Note the wanted exe on the right.**

=> community wiki

Comment: Is there any reason that `sqlite3.exe` is in external archive? It's so misleading for now.

Comment: Just a side note... this gives you the 32-bit version of SQLite!  Still no straightforward way to get 64-bit build on Windows.

Answer (score 6):

sqlite3.exe doesn't exist for 64 bit Windows OS. You can create your own by downloading the source code and building it.
Otherwise 32-bit exe will also work well on 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

You want to go **https://sqlite.org/download.html** this link and see below precompiled binary windows.

[Download this file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhyyS.png)

Extract and install sqlite3.exe

Done....................................................

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).