# How to compile a precompiled ".dll" SQLite file and get a ".exe" file for it's installation?

Tags: database, sqlite

[This is the page ref from where I am asked to download SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html)

I am not getting a ".exe" installer file in the zip file which is getting downloaded. How do I compile the precompiled ".dll" file so that I get the desired ".exe" file for installing SQLite Software? 
Any solutions? As I am a rookie, I would like to get a solution in layman words.

[SC of the files that I am getting after unzipping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWsfZ.png)

Comment: Are you looking for the command line shell program?

Comment: And why is this tagged mysql if you're asking something about sqlite?

Comment: Sorry sir I am new to Stackoverflow and I mistook it to be Instagram tagging, The issue is that .exe files are missing in the zip file after I downloaded SQLite. There are only two files, a .text and a .dll file. How to come up with a soluion to it?

Comment: You want the sqlite-tools-win32 zip file if you're looking for sqlite3.exe

Comment: Sir, please refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43050795/no-sqlite3-exe-in-sqlite3-download-folder-for-windows-64-bit. I have the same problem. The .exe file is missing from the zip file.The Library files are present but the .exe file is missing from the download zip file.

Comment: Again, just like that question's accepted answer says, and like I said earlier, you want the sqlite-tools-win32 zip file.

Comment: Yes can you send me the kit?

Comment: If you can't find it on the page you linked to in your question... I'm sorry, I can't help with that.